# Google Street View container inside Shiny Application

Tags: javascript, r, google-maps-api-3, shiny, rstudio

I have been trying to create a web application with an embedded Google Street View using RStudio's Shiny library; but have not been able to get the street view to render in the applicaiton.
I've been using the example JavaScript and HTML from:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed
which I paste here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View containers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var bryantPark = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869260, -122.254811);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: bryantPark,
    pov: {
      heading: 165,
      pitch: 0
    },
    zoom: 1
  };
  var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      panoramaOptions);
  myPano.setVisible(true);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My ui and server scripts are:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Google StreetView"),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("inc")
  )
))
```

and

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  getPage<-function() {
    return(includeHTML("googleStreetViewContainer.html"))
  }
  output$inc<-renderUI({getPage()})
})
```

I've tried a few different versions of the ui.R and server.R files by using includeHTML directly in the ui.R file rather than defining the getPage function and also using tags$script in the ui.R file.

I have not gotten any errors, but the Street View is not rendering. Any ideas?

Comment: The `googleVis` package allow you to integrate your web application with maps and graphs from google. You might want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with my [`googleway`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) package and a valid Google Maps API key

In Shiny you call `renderGoogle_map()` in the `server`, and `google_mapOutput()` in the `UI` to load the plot.

Then `google_map()` to run the map. When it's open you can access satellite / streetview as per usual on a Google Map

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(googleway)

df <- data.frame(lat = -37.817714,
                lon = 144.967260,
                info = "Flinders Street Station")

map_key <- "your_api_key_here"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box( google_mapOutput("myMap") )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){

    output$myMap <- renderGoogle_map({
        google_map(location = c(df$lat, df$lon), key = map_key, search_box = T)
     })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: can you feed `google_map()` with a reactive dataset? I tried but all I get is the Melbourne downtown :-)

Comment: @MLavoie The [shiny section](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/vignettes/googleway-vignette.Rmd#shiny) in the vignettte shows how to use a reactive data set. And if you use the `update_map_view = TRUE` argument the map will re-center to your data's location (but, it uses browser memory to do this, so you may want to call `clear_bounds()` at some point).

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response! I don't see in the link your provided how something like `google_map(key = map_key, data = df())` would work? In every example, it is a "static" dataset. Might worth asking a question on SO. thanks!

Comment: yeah maybe I don't understand your requirements. Please open a new question, or if you think it's an issue you can open an issue [on my github page](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues)

Comment: @MLavoie - I'm Intrigued - was it you needed to pass data to `google_map_update()` ?

Comment: It was a couple of mistakes here and there: my code was `google_map(key = map_key, data = data()) %>%
      add_circles(lat = "lat", lon = "long", info_window ="SuperficieLocal")`. So for instance, in `data()` if one the filter is not selected (`selected = FALSE`) then you get no data, and the map shows Melbourne. But when your data() is populated it get redirected to the right location. Great package btw!

Comment: @MLavoie a couple of hints: 1. you can use the `location` argument to set the initial location, 2. I would recommend using `google_map_update()` when you want to update the map with data, as it will update the existing map. If you continuously call `google_map()` you're loading a new map each time.

Comment: Is there a way to pull the location from the street view? For example, if a user moves the location, can we get the updated coordinates?

Comment: @nate does that functionality exist in Google Maps itself? Otherwise you can use one of the [events](http://symbolixau.github.io/googleway/articles/googleway-vignette.html#returning-data) to return data back to R

Comment: @SymbolixAU I am looking something more along the lines of getting the lat/lon of a street view whenever a user moves the view. Perhaps I should make a new question? I found this online: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view-service#StreetViewLocation

I was thinking of something like obsereEvent(input$myMap_streetview_click,{#return coordinates here})