# Which browser does Webshot Package uses in R

Tags: r

I wanna change the browser that Webshot package uses because i face a problem with it when i use it for google maps ... here's a pics that will show what i mean.

I only have 2 browsers .. google chrome and internet explorer .. i got url from google maps from chrome and  used `webshots()` on it to get a screenshot but it generated a similar pic with zooming out .. when i checked my internet explorer i found it an old version and using **lite mode** when i open google maps ... so i updated it to 11 and the problem solved when i open google maps when internet explorer but when i use `webshot()` i get the same problem ...

I'm using windows 7

so any way to solve this ? or is there another function that allows me to take screenshot for google traffic ?

here's the code i use

```
library(webshot)
URL <- "https://www.google.com.eg/maps/@30.0433147,31.2260969,16z/data=!5m1!1e1?hl=en"
webshot(URL, "r.jpeg")
```

here's a screenshot for google maps using google chrome i took manually 
[image]

here's another screenshot for google maps using the last update of internet explrore 
[image]

here's what i get when i use `webshot()`
[image]

Comment: webshot is written with PhantomJS, but if you use RSelenium, you can use anything you can configure. It's a bit more work, though. What are you actually trying to do? R (with packages) has a lot of mapping capabilities, some of which use Google Maps through its APIs.

Comment: As @alistaire says, you can embed a google map with traffic layers, satellite view, street view, etc in R using the [development version](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/NEWS.md) of my googleway package. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39198783/5977215) for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses PhantomJS to load the page as per its documentation:
https://github.com/wch/webshot

Comment: How to change PhantomJS to use chrome in taking screenshots?

Comment: That wouldn't be possible without writing your own R package that uses webkit. (Chrome doesn't use Chrome to browse the internet, it uses webkit)

Comment: hmmm, how can i update PhantomJS to carry the full mode of google maps ? i tried to find it's path and remove it then download it again but couldn't find it

Comment: Not only is that not possible, it wouldn't help you. Consider the Google Maps Lite documentation: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: I did, and that's why i updated my internet explorer to 11 ... but nothing changed .

Comment: Also it sounds like you are trying to view many locations in Google Maps. You should know that Google will ban your IP address from using maps if you use it too much without getting an API key.

Comment: Ok,
I understand now know why you are having trouble getting this to work. You are missing a fundamental understanding of how Webshot works and what PhantomJS is. PhantomJS is a browser like IE but its not installed on your computer. Its run from the Webshot code.

Comment: i installed it using the `install_phantomjs` function in webshot package ... do u mean i should install it manually ?

Comment: No, its not that. In the Google Maps documentation it lists the specific types of browsers it supports. It does not list the phantomJS browser. 
If you are going to use the Webshot package you have to be happy with Maps Lite as it uses a browser that isn't supported by the full version of Google Maps.